# How do I use select with date condition?

Tags: sql, sql-server

In sqlserver, how do I compare dates?
For example:

Select * from Users where RegistrationDate >= '1/20/2009'

(RegistrationDate is datetime type)

Thanks

Answer (score 21):

If you put in

```
SELECT * FROM Users WHERE RegistrationDate >= '1/20/2009'
```

it will automatically convert the string `'1/20/2009'` into the `DateTime` format for a date of `1/20/2009 00:00:00`. So by using `>=` you should get every user whose registration date is 1/20/2009 or more recent.

Edit: I put this in the comment section but I should probably link it here as well. This is an article detailing some more in depth ways of working with DateTime's in you queries: http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/2209321/Working-with-SQL-Server-DateTime-Variables-Part-Three---Searching-for-Particular-Date-Values-and-Ranges.htm

Comment: Some more information concerning DateTime datatypes and SQL Server queries can be found here: http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/2209321/Working-with-SQL-Server-DateTime-Variables-Part-Three---Searching-for-Particular-Date-Values-and-Ranges.htm

Answer (score 5):

if you do not want to be bothered by the date format, you could compare the column with the general date format, for example

`select * 
From table 
where cast (RegistrationDate as date)  between '20161201' and '20161220'`

make sure the date is in DATE format, otherwise `cast (col as DATE)`

Answer (score 4):

```
Select * from Users where RegistrationDate >= CONVERT(datetime, '01/20/2009', 103)
```

is safe to use, independent of the date settings on the server.

The full list of styles can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

```
select sysdate from dual
30-MAR-17

select count(1) from masterdata where to_date(inactive_from_date,'DD-MON-YY'
between '01-JAN-16' to '31-DEC-16'

12998 rows
```

Comment: The 'where' clause in this solution is not SARG-able, so indexes won't be hit.

Answer (score 1):

Another feature is **between**:

```
Select * from table where date between '2009/01/30' and '2009/03/30'
```

Answer (score 0):

I always get the filter date into a datetime, with no time (time= 00:00:00.000)

```
DECLARE @FilterDate  datetime --final destination, will not have any time on it
DECLARE @GivenDateD  datetime --if you're given a datetime
DECLARE @GivenDateS  char(23) --if you're given a string, it can be any valid date format, not just the yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm:ss.mmm that I'm using

SET @GivenDateD='2009/03/30 13:42:50.123'
SET @GivenDateS='2009/03/30 13:42:50.123'

--remove the time and assign it to the datetime
@FilterDate=dateadd(dd, datediff(dd, 0, @FilterDateD), 0)
--OR
@FilterDate=dateadd(dd, datediff(dd, 0, @FilterDateS), 0)
```

You can use this WHERE clause to then filter:

```
WHERE ColumnDateTime>=@FilterDate AND ColumnDateTime<@FilterDate+1
```

this will give all matches that are on or after the beginning of the day on 2009/03/30 up to and including the complete day on 2009/03/30

you can do the same for START and END filter parameters as well.  Always make the start date a datetime and use zero time on the day you want, and make the condition ">=".  Always make the end date the zero time on the day after you want and use "<".  Doing that, you will always include any dates properly, regardless of the time portion of the date.