# using <= or >= in timestamp field in mysql

Tags: mysql

I would like to select all records before `2014-03-22` date:

```
 where date < 2014-03-22 // what I need
```

but below code doesn't see 2013 year's records :

```
SELECT * FROM `tractions` WHERE YEAR(date) <= 2014  AND MONTH(date) <= 3 and  DAY(date) <= 22 and succ = 1
```

Comment: following link may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/696438/how-do-i-use-select-with-date-condition

Comment: That second query is not only over-complicating things, it's completely wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there anything wrong with:

```
SELECT * FROM tractions
WHERE date < '2014-03-22'    -- place the date, correctly formatted, in quotes
```

Since this comparison doesn't use any functions, it will also allow you to use any indices setup on the `date` column.