# SQL queries with date format "dd/MM/yyyy " in Microsoft SQL Server Compact

Tags: sql, date, format

I am using SQL serverce(Microsoft SQL Server Compact)
I have problem with the dates when queering database. I am saving  dates in database into nvarchar fields with this format "dd/MM/yyyy" 
for example,when I use this statement

```
select * from ClientAccounts where  clientAccount_Date > '29/07/2019'
```

I get this in result 30/06/2019

I even tried this format

```
convert(nvarchar(10),clientAccount_Date,103) > '29/07/2019'
```

I got the same results
anyone can help me please in this issue.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Did you mean *Microsoft SQL Server Compact*? I think you should consider tagging your question accordingly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I use select with date condition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/696438/how-do-i-use-select-with-date-condition)

Comment: I am not able to add tag like  Microsoft SQL Server Compact

Comment: If you received a valid answer, please mark it accordingly

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from ClientAccounts where  clientAccount_Date > '29-07-2019'
```

In SQL, normally you use '-' instead of '/'.

Hope this works.

Comment: You will need to change the format on SQL
Doing this:

Comment: select convert(varchar, getdate(), 23)   ---- transforming into 2006-12-30

Answer (score 0):

Try casting the string into a date. Something like select * from ClientAccounts where  clientAccount_Date > cast('29/07/2019' as date)

Comment: thank you for your replay.  tried and got this exception
{"The specified data type is not valid. [ Data type (if known) = date ]"}

Comment: I tried it out using SQL Server and it worked fine, but I had to change the date to MM/DD/YYYY, so:  `cast('07/29/2019' as Date)`
It's also possible your column is a DateTime so you'd have to use: `cast('07/29/2019' as DateTime)`

Comment: I am using Microsoft SQL Server Compact

Comment: my  column type in the table  is nvarcar. I had to do it like that. This is my first time to use Microsoft SQL Server Compact.  but I was not able to save date with the format dd/MM/yyyy unless I change it to nvarchar

Comment: Then cast both sides like this `select * from ClientAccounts where cast(clientAccount_Date as date) > cast('29/07/2019' as date)`

Answer (score 0):

I generally use the YYYYMMDD format:

```
select * from ClientAccounts where  clientAccount_Date > '20190729'
```